# Set of linear transformations is a set of sets?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the set $S = \{T ~ \mid ~ T : V \to W\}$ where $V,W$ are fixed vector spaces over field $F$. I have encountered this many a times, or similar things like the set of functions $f:A\to B$ (also written as $B^A)$.

1. My question is, are they the set of all elements (as in, $\{f_1(v_1), f_1(v_2),\cdots, f_2(w_1), f_2(w_2), \cdots \}$ of all functions that fall under the given definition or is it the set of sets where the second *set* is the set of function values. For this case, it can be represented by $\{f_1,f_2,\cdots\}$ where each $f_i$ is a set of function values. Or is it just the set of functions where the function values (the range set) isn't of a concern?
2. Now, how do we represent this set? $\{f ~ | ~ f : A \to B\}$ or $\{f(X) ~ | ~ f : A \to B\}$ ? If they mean different, please explain the difference.

Note : I understand that the way I wrote in (1) works only when the domain of the function is countable and the set of functions are countable too. I don't mean countability here; I couldn't think of a better way to express it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The elements of a set of functions are *functions*, regardless of the specific values they take, as in your last suggestion. 
   Nevertheless, functions $f$ can be rigorously defined as the set of *pairs* of the form $(x,f(x))$, but this is irrelevant here.
2. $\{f\mid f:A\to B\}$ denotes the set of all functions $A\to B$, while
   $\{f(X)\mid f:A\to B\}$ denotes the set of the images $f(X)\subseteq B$ of $X\subseteq A$ under all possible functions $f:A\to B$. 
   So that its elements are *subsets* of $B$, and not functions.

Comment: Okay so, $\{f(X) ~ | ~ f : A \to B\}$ is of the form $\{ \{~ \},\{~\}, \cdots, \}$ or just $\{\cdots\}$? (the second corresponds to a set of elements where each element is not a set itself.

Comment: Well, under current most widely accepted set theory, namely ZFC, *everything is a set*. In particular, as wrote in my answer, a function can be defined as a set of pairs, where pairs themselves are defined as specific sets.. There are however other base theories, so we don't need to insist on this viewpoint. A function is just a function: it inputs an element from $A$ and outputs an element of $B$, and does it consequently.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I answered the other question. The set of $f(X)$'s is a subset of the powerset of $B$, so yes, $\{\{\dots\}, \dots \}$.

Comment: I see, makes more sense now. Thank you!